# Cannot read DOM attribute from script loaded dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Including a script statically in the HTML like the one below works:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://meerkatapp.co/widgets/embed.js" data-mute="false" data-social="false" data-cover="default" data-type="square" data-username="jessicadelfino"></script>
```

However, invoking the script dynamically doesn't work.

JavaScript code:

```
    // Create script object
    var script = document.createElement("script");

    // Configure script with Meerkat data
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://meerkatapp.co/widgets/embed.js";
    script.setAttribute("data-mute", "false");
    script.setAttribute("data-social", "false");
    script.setAttribute("data-cover", "default");
    script.setAttribute("data-type", "square");
    script.setAttribute("data-username", "jessicadelfino");

    // Append script object
    $("body").append(script);
```

Here's where the error occurs (from `http://meerkatapp.co/widgets/embed.js`):

```
window.currentScript = document.currentScript || (function() {
  var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
  return scripts[scripts.length - 1];
})();

main(window.currentScript)

function main(currentScript) {
      ...
      var btnContainerElm = currentScript
      var mkBtnUsername = btnContainerElm.getAttribute("data-username")
      ...
      mkBtnUsername = mkBtnUsername.replace("@", '')
```

This code generates the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null` on the line `mkBtnUsername = mkBtnUsername.replace("@", '').`

Clearly `mkBtnUsername` is not set even though the `data-username` attribute is set in the script.

Comment: Where is the username set? Please show us everything.

Comment: @ user2864740 Yes, please read the question. It's null, but the issue is the code works fine when done statically, so why is username coming up as `null`.

Comment: @Script47 The username is set in the last line before appending the script to the body. Thanks for asking.

Comment: `script.setAttribute("data-username", "jessicadelfino");` that?

Comment: @Script47 Sorry, updated the question to make things clearer.

Comment: @Crashalot are you using any `HTML`?

Comment: Sorry? You have almost 5k rep, but you are unable to find a null reference by yourself?

Comment: As @user2864740 said, it also means that this `var btnContainerElm = currentScript` isn't working correctly. Which is probably causing all the other issues.

Comment: @user2864740 There is a minimal test case (static vs dynamic), and all the relevant code was posted (though more clearly now, so thanks for pointing that out). Yes, it's clear what is `null` -- the question is why does it occur. Can you clarify why async execution matters since the attributes are set *before* the script runs (at least in theory)?

Comment: @JK Thanks for asking. This isn't about finding the `null` reference, which is pretty easy to spot. The question is about why a dynamic invocation of the script produces a different result from a static invocation. Can you help answer this question?

Comment: `currentScript = ...;` where is this?

Comment: @StefanBaiu Caught me too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript

Comment: @user2864740 Yes, the sync vs async execution is clear ... ok, here's the core question, which was clear in the question title but maybe less clear in the question body: should it matter if a script is executed dynamically?

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks for editing the question and adding clarification.

Comment: @Crashalot Take some time to clean up the question and focus on - ie. test & state - that `btnContainerElm.getAttribute("data-username")` is not what is set in the SCRIPT element (ie. "is null"). Leave only one attribute.

Comment: @user2864740 yeah, but it is `document.currentScript`, not `window.currentScript` (so it cannot be a global variable)

Comment: @StefanBaiu Hmm. Good point. Then why is there no ReferenceException? I'm out of this one ..

Comment: @user2864740 yeah I know, maybe he cached the value into a local var, I think more source code would make things a little more clear

Comment: @StefanBaiu Updated the question with more source code for `currentScript` ... thanks for the great questions and tips on improving the question while fostering a constructive, positive atmosphere.

Comment: @Crashalot hmm, my guess is `document.currentScript` is probably null (it can happen if it is called inside of an event handler, say `document.ready`), and your fallback function is choosing a wrong script (`scripts[scripts.length - 1]`). Try to log `window.currentScript`.

Comment: @StefanBaiu Yup, that's my guess, too. Found a solution; thanks for your help! Would love to award you points for maintaining such a constructive attitude while helping to refine the question and find an answer. SO needs more role models like you who can help well-intentioned users improve questions without snark and without poisoning the atmosphere. Can you post the last comment as an answer?

Comment: @Crashalot - could you share your solution here? I'm running into the same issue and haven't found a workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is `document.currentScript` is probably **null** (it can happen if that property is checked inside of an event handler, say `$(document).ready`), and your fallback function is choosing the wrong script (`scripts[scripts.length - 1]`). Try to log `window.currentScript`.